# Elasticsearch typeahead query optimization

Tags: elasticsearch

I am currently working on typeahead support (with contains, not just starts-with) for over 100.000.000 entries (and that number could grow arbitrarily) using ElasticSearch.
The current setup works, but I was wondering if there is a better approach to it.

I'm using AWS Elasticsearch, so I don't have full control over the cluster.

My index is defined as follows:

```
{
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "ngram_analyzer": {
                "tokenizer": "ngram_tokenizer",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase"
                ]
            },
            "edge_ngram_analyzer": {
                "tokenizer": "edge_ngram_tokenizer",
                "filter": "lowercase"
            },
            "search_analyzer": {
                "tokenizer": "keyword",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase"
                ]
            }
        },
        "tokenizer": {
            "ngram_tokenizer": {
                "type": "ngram",
                "min_gram": 3,
                "max_gram": 300,
                "token_chars": [
                    "letter",
                    "digit",
                    "symbol",
                    "punctuation",
                    "whitespace"
                ]
            },
            "edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
                "type": "edge_ngram",
                "min_gram": 3,
                "max_gram": 300,
                "token_chars": [
                        "letter",
                        "digit",
                        "symbol",
                        "punctuation",
                        "whitespace"
                    ]
            }
        }
    }
},
"mappings": {
    "account": {
        "properties": {
            "tags": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer"
            },
            "tags_prefix": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer"
            },
            "tenantId": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "keyword"
            },
            "referenceId": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The structure of the documents is:

```
{
   "tenantId": "1234",
   "name": "A NAME",
   "referenceId": "1234567",
   "tags": [
       "1234567",
       "A NAME"
   ],
   "tags_prefix": [
       "1234567",
       "A NAME"
   ]
}
```

The point behind the structure is that documents have *searcheable* fields, over which typeahead works, it's not over everything in the document, so it could be things not even in the document itself.

The search query is:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "highlight": {
      "fields": {
          "tags": {}
      }
  },
  "query": {
      "bool": {
          "must": {
              "multi_match": {
                  "query": "a nam",
                  "fields": ["tags_prefix^100", "tags"]
              }
          },
          "filter": {
              "term": {
                  "tenantId": "1234"
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

I'm doing a *multi_match* because, while I need typeahead, the results that have the match at the start need to come back first, so I followed the recommendation in [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/match-phrase-score-by-order/116771)

The current setup is 10 shards, 3 master nodes (t2.mediums), 2 data/ingestion nodes (t2.mediums) with 35GB EBS disk on each, which I know is **tiny** given the final needs of the system, but useful enough for experimenting.
I have ~6000000 records inserted, and the response time with a cold cache is around 300ms.

I was wondering if this is the right approach or are there some optimizations I could implement to the index/query to make this more performant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think that the solution you build is good, and the optimisations you are looking for should only be considered if you have an issue with the current solution, meaning the queries are too slow. No need for pre-mature optimisations.

Second, I think that you don't need to provide the tags_prefix in your docs. all you need is to use the edge_ngram_tokenizer on the tags field, which will create the desired prefix tokens for the search to work. you can use [multi fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) in order to have multiple tokenizers for the same 'tags' field.

Third, use the edge_ngram_tokenizer settings carefully, especially the 'min_gram' and 'max_gram' settings. the reason is that having too high max_gram will:
a. create too many prefix tokens, will use too much space
b. decrease the index rate, as indexing takes longer
c. is not useful - you don't expect auto-complete to take into account 300 prefix characters. a better max prefix token settings should be (to my opinion) in the range of 10-20 characters max (or even less).

Good luck!